# Using Nginx as micro service API gateway

Tags: node.js, nginx, docker, kubernetes, microservices

We are splitting our monolith API into micro services.

We do not need rate-limiting, auth, caching or any other gateway like abilities.

Would it be a valid approach to use very simple stateless Nginx containers that route to the underlying services?

Comment: Yes we are using kubernetes

Comment: Are you asking about using Nginx in front of Kubernetes? Have it route to the services you define?

Comment: No asking about using Nginx as an API gateway within a cluster. Would be a deployment and associated service

Comment: Isn't that kind of what [services](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/#defining-a-service) are for?

Comment: Perhaps, although it ties us to kubernetes

Comment: CAn services do layer 7 http routing?

Comment: According to the docs, there is some layer 7 routing support. I'm not sure what you mean about being *tied* to kubernetes. If you wanted to switch away from it to say Mesos or Swarm, you'd have to re-work part of your architecture anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Nginx can be a deployment and a service (of loadbalancer or externalIP type) and can forward to upstream services.

You might have to frequently change the nginx.conf though (when you add/remove services), so I would recommend using a ConfigMap to keep your nginx.conf and mounting that as a volume in your deployment. Refer: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/configmap/ and scroll down to consume configmap via volumes.

Another thing to keep in mind is that if you delete and create a service that is referred to in nginx.conf as an upstream service, you'll have to restart your deployment because nginx resolves all service DNS labels when nginx starts.

Answer (score 0):

nginx ingress controller will do the job: https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/tree/master/ingress/controllers/nginx